# Jenkins Jelly view: How to aggregate multiple checkboxs to display in a single row?

Tags: maven, jenkins, jelly

Though I have been using jenkins for a while, this is my first time to write(modify) an jenkins plugin using maven and jelly syntax.

My question is mostly regarding the view layer which is implemented by jelly. Currently I have a a config.jelly as below:

```
<j:jelly xmlns:j="jelly:core" xmlns:st="jelly:stapler" xmlns:d="jelly:define" xmlns:l="/lib/layout" xmlns:t="/lib/hudson" xmlns:f="/lib/form">

  <f:entry title="SUCCESS" field="success">
    <f:checkbox field="success" checked="${success}"/>
  </f:entry>

  <f:entry title="FAILURE" field="fail">
    <f:checkbox field="fail" checked="${fail}"/>
  </f:entry>

  <f:entry title="UNSTABLE" field="unstable">
    <f:checkbox field="unstable" checked="${unstable}"/>
  </f:entry>

  <f:entry title="ABORTED" field="aborted">
    <f:checkbox field="aborted" checked="${aborted}"/>
  </f:entry>

</j:jelly>
```

And it looks like this with each checkbox in a row which is a bit ugly.
[image]

**My question is how to aggregate these 4 row into one single row ? Does anyone has know how to?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I found the way to do this:

```
<j:jelly xmlns:j="jelly:core" xmlns:st="jelly:stapler" xmlns:d="jelly:define" xmlns:l="/lib/layout" xmlns:t="/lib/hudson" xmlns:f="/lib/form">

   <f:entry title="Popo Id" field="ids">
      <f:textbox field="ids" />
    </f:entry>

   <f:entry>
    <f:checkbox default="false" name="success" id="success"/>
    <label>SUCCESS</label>
    &amp;nbsp;&amp;nbsp;

    <f:checkbox default="false" name="fail" id="fail"/>
    <label>FAILURE</label>
     &amp;nbsp;&amp;nbsp;

    <f:checkbox default="false" name="unstable" id="unstable"/>
    <label>UNSTABLE</label>
    &amp;nbsp;&amp;nbsp;   

    <f:checkbox default="false" name="aborted" id="aborted"/>
    <label>ABORTED</label>
  </f:entry>

</j:jelly>
```

And the aggregated 4 checkboxes are looks like this:
[image]